# Android's Fingerprint Scanner as gateway to enrol multiple fingerprints and generate Asymmetric Keys

Tags: android, encryption, private-key, fingerprint, encryption-asymmetric

Is it possible to use the Android's Fingerprint Scanner as gateway for generating Asymmetric Keys.

The phone is used to enrol multiple fingerprints, generate the Asymmetric Keys and send the public key to an online database (if possible via sms).

All the private key are destroyed or saved by the user as an mnemonic password.

Answer (score 0):

For a GMS certified device, you won't be able to access any fingerprint-specific info on Android 6.0+. So I don't believe you can generate an asymmetric key from it as no unique information can be obtained from the TEE.

See: https://source.android.com/compatibility/7.1/android-7.1-cdd.pdf

Section: 7.3.10

Highlights:

- MUST have a hardware-backed keystore implementation, and perform the
  fingerprint matching in a Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) or on a
  chip with a secure channel to the TEE.
- MUST have all identifiable fingerprint data encrypted and
  cryptographically authenticated such that they cannot be acquired,
  read or altered outside of the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) as
  documented in the implementation guidelines on the Android Open
  Source Project site.
- MUST NOT enable 3rd-party applications to distinguish between
  individual fingerprints.

The fingerprint API seems to only be able to authenticate the fingerprint and little else: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html